# Relation between type of material and tension developed by Laplace law

Tags: classical-mechanics

[The Laplace law for the a cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_stress) that relates the excess pressure $P$ in the cylinder to the hoop stress in the walls $T$ can be written as:

$$ P = \frac{T w}{r } $$

where $w$ is the thickness of the cylinder wall and $r$ is the radius of the cylinder.

My question is: for 2 different materials say glass and steel (with different Young's modulus) for the same pressure and radius will the tension produced in the wall vary?

Comment: I don't recognise the equation you give. What is the difference between the width of the cylinder $w$ and the radius $r$? Isn't the equation usually $\sigma=Pr/t$, where $\sigma$ is the stress in the wall?

Comment: radius and width can be used interchangeably i guess. The equation is wall tension=pressure×radius i think

Comment: So $w/r$ in your equation means $w$ or $r$? And $t$ is the wall tension? Can you edit your question to clarify exactly what you mean?

Comment: radius means the radius of the lumen and w means the thickness of the vessel wall. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The equation you cite comes from the [Young-Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation) and is derived by balancing the force from the wall tension against the force from the internal pressure. It is independent of the material that makes up the cylinder so it would be the same for glass and steel, and indeed anything else.

Comment: okay it is independent of the material used. Thank you